# How to deploy to Heroku a Node.js app that keeps posting to an endpoint?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I created a very simple Node app with a single function that keeps hitting every three seconds a POST endpoint. It consoles back the number of times it has posted alongside with the response's code. Here's the full code inside a file called `fetch.js`:

```
const request = require('request');

let counter = 0

function vote(){
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://voting-vote-producer.r7.com/vote',
        headers: {
          authority: 'voting-vote-producer.r7.com',
          'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36',
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          accept: '*/*',
          origin: 'https://afazenda.r7.com',
          'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
          'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
          'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
          referer: 'https://afazenda.r7.com/a-fazenda-12/votacao',
          'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8'
        },
        form: {voting_id: '268', alternative_id: '648'},
      };
      
      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
      
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(`votos: `, counter)

        counter++
      })
}

setInterval(vote, 3000)
```

I then created a script on `package.json` as per Heroku's specification:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "node fetch.js"
  },
...
```

If I run locally by either `npm start` or `node fetch.js` it works. I can see it in the console logs.

However, after deploying successfully to Heroku, I keep getting an error as per Heroku logs:

```
2020-11-19T15:15:02.738228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-19T15:15:05.839197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-19T15:15:09.505292+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-19T15:15:09.505330+00:00 app[web.1]: > fazenda@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-19T15:15:09.505331+00:00 app[web.1]: > node fetch.js
2020-11-19T15:15:09.505331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-19T15:16:06.107217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-11-19T15:16:06.130433+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-11-19T15:16:06.251368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-11-19T15:16:06.326134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch, you don't have a port where the app runs, you need a server, you can't just deploy a function that does something, try to add an express server and inside that server do what you want to do

Comment: Create a `Procfile` with the content `worker: node fetch.js`. You are running a web process and it is epecting you to bind to the `$PORT`
The `Procfile` defines a new process which is not a web process. Thus it is not expecting to bind to the port.

Answer (score 0):

You should create [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) with `worker: node fetch.js`. Go to Heroku and change dyno formation from `npm start` to `node fetch.js`

Comment: I did exactly as you told, and now I am getting the following:
`2020-11-19T22:37:36.627501+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-11-19T22:37:37.762640+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-11-19T22:37:37.878441+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-11-19T22:37:39.392500+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command node fetch.js
2020-11-19T22:37:40.213464+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up`

I did restart dynos, but still get the same error

Comment: @VellerBauer As I can see the main problem is "Stopping all processes with SIGTERM". The application processes have 30 seconds to shut down cleanly. During this time they should stop accepting new requests and attempt to finish their current requests, or put jobs back on the queue for other worker processes to handle. If any processes remain after that time period, the dyno manager will terminate them forcefully with SIGKILL. Try to change setInterval function, set the number of seconds to larger number.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. Unfortunately I am still getting SIGKILL, even after changing `setInterval` to 300000. Any other ideas?

Comment: @VellerBauer I found description of a similar problem in official [FAQ](https://help.heroku.com/ROG3H81R/why-does-sigterm-handling-not-work-correctly-in-nodejs-with-npm) and [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm). Hope it can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

By default, Heroku requires an HTTP server to work. So you just create an HTTP server which doesn't do anything. You can use the build-in [HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTP-server/) for that.

For example, add following to your app:

```
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello, World!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
// this should be the last line
server.listen(parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080);
```

Please note, that if Heroku passes the required port using the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried and am still getting this error: `2020-11-19T23:03:40.260718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-11-19T23:03:40.343055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-11-19T23:03:41.324094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command node index.js
2020-11-19T23:03:45.483422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up`. I also uploaded the full code [here](https://github.com/veller/bot-votacao-a-fazenda) in case it helps debugging